# Change Unity Sprite during run time programmatically

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity so this seems like a very basic question but I've been working on it for a while and google and Unity Docs hasn't helped much so:

I want to change the Health sprite shown here:

[image]

When my LoseCollider at the bottom of the screen gets triggered. The sprite would change to a 2 health and a 1 health sprite:

[image]

In code I'd like to have:

```
if (health == 3) {
 // Switch to 3 hearts sprite.
 }
 else if (health == 2) {
 // Switch to 2 hearts sprite.
 }
 else if (health == 1) {
 // Switch to 1 heart sprite.
 }
```

Based on my current code:

[image]

[image]

How can I change my Sprites?

[image]

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? How does your program react?

Comment: It tells me that I need a sprite renderer but as you can see at the top, it has a sprite renderer. The script that is asking for it is the "lose collider"

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I think I saw the problem.
Use this code instead:

```
    HealthManager hManager;
void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D trigger)
{
    if (hManager.totalHealth >= 3)
    {
        hManager.LoadHealthSprites();
        hManager.totalHealth--;
    }
    else
    {
        levelManager = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<LevelManager>();
        levelManager.LoadLevel("Lose");
    }
}

void Start()
{
    hManager = hpManager.GetComponent<HealthManager>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I changed and saved my script and upon run time: When the Sprite should change image i get this error "The variable hpManager of LoseCollider has not been assigned.
You probably need to assign the hpManager variable of the LoseCollider script in the inspector."

Comment: @Memj in the inspector, drag the hpManager gameobject to the loseCollider script. It should say something like "hpManager [empty]" so drag the hpmanager object to that box.

Comment: That was already done. (I'm editing the question to show the image proof)

Comment: Your structure is so confusing which is making this harder o.O Looks like that structure is probably ripped from Unity tutorials, which are not always the best ones. I'll edit the answer and see if you can fix the problem you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(HealthManager.totalHealth>=3) 
{

}
```

I think there is an logical error. it will never call LoadHealthSprite func if totalHealth is smaller than 3. Change this part as:

```
if(HealthManager.totalHealth>0)
{

}
```